# Checkbox in UITableView change and revert images

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, checkbox, swift2

I have a tableView with custom tableViewCell. Each cell has an image on the left (see screen 1). The custom tableViewCell has been subclassed. Every row has a different image which depends on indexPath.row

If I click on the image(s) the screen, the images should change to tick boxes so user can multiselect (see screen 2). If I click back on the image with a tick, it should revert back to old image on screen 1.

[image: Screen 1]    [image: Screen 2]

**Issue :** 
I know how to change the image to tick mark but don't know how to go back to old image (pls remember every row has a different image - so the "else" part in my below code will not make sense).

Below is my code to change and revert the image

```
@IBAction func imageTap(sender: AnyObject) {    
    let imageView : UIImageView! = sender.view! as! UIImageView
    if imageView.image != UIImage(named: "Oval 5"){
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Oval 5")
        awardBadge.hidden = false
    }
    else // Need to figure out how to go back to same image
    {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Oval 1") 
        awardBadge.hidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: is the else case ever reached? I doubt the image comparison is the correct way to go, you should add some properties to the cell (or the container of the cells to account for dequeues etc.) containing wether it is checked or not and contain the UIImage that should be displayed if it is not checked.

Comment: try to use this in order to compare 2 UIImage `func equal(image1 : UIImage , image2:UIImage) -> Bool {
 
 guard let data1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1) else {return false}
 guard let data2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image2) else {return false}
 
 return data1.isEqualToData(data2)
}` also you might override `==`

Answer (score 2):

Add a boolean named "isTicked", or something like that, to your cell and set it to the right value at selecting / deselecting. Based on this value, you can set the right image. Let the cell do the rest.

Comparing images makes it unnecessarily complex and less performing.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should track selected items. The easiest way would be to define an array of booleans in the view controller's subclass.
2. Define the delegate for you UITableViewCell's subclass like:

   ```
   protocol MYCustomCellDelegate {
    func didSelectedCell(cell: MYCustomCell)
   }
   ```

And handle it in your controller:

```
func didSelectedCell(cell: MYCustomCell)
{
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(cell: cell)
    selectedItems[indexPath.row] = !selectedItems[indexPath.row]
    tableView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
}
```

3. In the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method set the state of you cell according to the `selectedItems[indexPath.row]`. If it is selected show the checkbox, if it is not - image:

   ```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MYCustomCell
       cell.setTitle(titles[indexPath.row])
       cell.setSelected(selectedItems[indexPath.row])
       cell.delegate = self
       return cell
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

[image]i think you approach would be different, why don't you use the custom image button with 2 different images which represents selected and normal state. available states are normal/highlighted/selected/disabled. when we have custom image button, since you are using the static images, you would use your images for default state and tick image for selected state. all you have to do is just use the inbuilt property **selected**.

Comment: problem is that I want to multi select..so the moment I select another image the tick mark goes away from the first image..if there is a soln pls let me know..also did not find selected state --only saw highlighted state

Comment: check in storyboard, you should have for buttons, PFA in my answer

Comment: is there a way without using buttons - eventually i want to create the images using drawRect?

Comment: can you try this and let me know, if it works.
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Oval 1",
            inBundle: NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType),
            compatibleWithTraitCollection: self.traitCollection)

Comment: can you pls provide some more code..im new to iOS..and not sure what and where you want me to try the above code